# Can fighter jets still fly with their radios being jammed?

Tags: fighter, radio

Imagine a scenario, a squadron flies through an area and suddenly their radio is getting jammed. Even when they try to go back, it's still getting jammed. Would something bad happen if they can't escape the frequency?

Comment: are you confusing radio jamming and EMPs?

Comment: What is your definition of ‘bad’ in this scenario?

Comment: If you're concerned that the planes would just fall out of the sky because of some radio frequency noise, then no, that won't happen. An EMP (Electromagnetic Pulse) could, conceivably, cause the electronics that control all modern fighter aircraft to fail, however, they're hardened against EMP damage, so that's not guaranteed to happen, and even if it did, it doesn't mean the aircraft will immediately start to tumble out of control.

Comment: They wouldn't be very useful if a few jammed frequencies kept them from operating.

Answer (score 5):

There are a bunch of different "radios" on an airplane.

- There is a radio for voice communications with other airplanes and Air Traffic Control.
  The airplanes can clearly fly without talking to anyone, just an increased risk of getting to close to other planes or not coordinating properly.
- There are navigation radios that are Receive-Only, such as VOR, NDB, GPS, and ILS. If the jammer can prevent the signal from being received, these services go out.  These are very handy services to have, but are not essential for safe flight.  Flying without them will make navigation and landing more difficult, but not impossible. (especially if visibility is good).
- There are navigation radios that are Transmit and Receive, such as DME and ADSB. These could be jammed either to stop the transmission from the airplane or the reception at the airplane.  Again, losing these services would hinder navigation and awareness, but are not critical to safe flight.
- There is sometimes a radio-altimeter that that can determine height above the ground.
  This is typically only used on Landing, and not critical to flight or landing.
- There are probably several other radios that may or may not be present on airplanes, such as ACARS, but none are essential to fighter jets safe operation.

Its not clear what you mean by *"something bad"*, but well trained military pilots would be able to fly,  complete a mission, return and land, using nothing more than a pilot's eyeballs and training. (although with slightly increased risk without all the wonderful technology)

Comment: Technically the pilot's eyeballs use "radio" as well... in the terahertz frequency band.

Comment: Technically, @randomhead, that can get "jammed" as well. That's why it's a US federal crime to point lasers at planes in flight.

Comment: The one most likely to be a problem is the IFF system. If air defences cannot identify the plane as a friend that could result in "something bad happening".

Answer (score 3):

Just to make sure you understand the concept of "signal jamming": simply put it means disturbing the signal such that communication (data transfer) becomes impossible due to noise. It does not mean locking up of the devices using the frequency range being jammed. So a situation where radio jamming is present does not mean a certain frequency cannot be "escaped", it means the frequency range becomes unusable.

Operating fighter jets (or pretty much any aircraft) is not critically dependent on radios being functional. For sure it will complicate things to a certain extent, but there are procedures to follow in case radios fail or frequencies are being jammed.

Fighter "squadron" on a mission has pre planned and practiced scenarios where radio operability is lost. Depending on type of mission, the mission may continue with other means of communication (data link), it may be aborted, or anything in between (for example switch to secondary goals/targets if coordinated strike is no longer possible).

P.S. A fighter squadron is quite a large unit, about 12 to 24 aircraft, it is unlikely a whole squadron would perform a single mission in unison. More likely unit pro perform a coordinated single operation would be "a flight" which is a third or a quarter of a squadron: [Wikipedia - Squadron (aviation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squadron_(aviation))

Comment: Well when I say squadron I thought it would be like 5 or 4 aircrafts. But what if (just pretend) the mission they're going has some kind of jamming signal on the area but they need to go through since there's something in that area they need to destroy?

Comment: In the case of a strike mission, the mission plan  will be such that once the aircraft are in the target area, no communications are necessary. They can carry out the mission without any communications and return to base after that.

Comment: Military maxim I learned early: "Comms are the first thing to go."

Comment: Absolutely @WilliamWalkerIII  that's why a lot of the military training aims at hight operational capability as a team even with poor or non existent comms.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how technology in this field has advanced since 1992 or so when I retired, but back at that time, it was not possible (due to power requirements), to jam the *entire* VHF or UHF radio spectrum from a distance with enough power to inhibit communications between transceivers that are closer together (inverse square law). So Jammers had to detect which frequency or frequencies were in use and concentrate jamming energy on them. This fact allowed creative solutions to the jamming problem (details of which *were* at that time classified).